# How do I get TFS 2015 to parse 3 digit versioning for NuGet packaging

Tags: tfs, nuget, semantic-versioning, packager

When I set my TFS 2015 build definition, that is creating a NuGet package, I set the Build Number format with:

> $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Major).$(Minor)$(rev:.r)

Where Major and Minor or just variables that I defined.  When I use the step "NuGet Packager", I get the error:

> Could not find version number data in BUILD_BUILDNUMBER.

When I use 4 digits, I don't get the error.  How do I get it to work with semantic versioning?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

1) You need to get access to your Build Agent machine

2) Navigate to where the Build Agent is installed.
      For me --> C:\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetPackager

3) You will see folder versions, so go into the latest one.

4) Modify the PowerShell script, NuGetPackager.ps1

> Find --> $VersionRegex = "\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+"
>
> And replace with --> $VersionRegex = "\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+|\d+.\d+.\d+"

5) And then save the script.

What I am doing is modifying the regular expression to say "Search for the pattern #.#.#.# OR #.#.# in the build number string".  Whereas before it was only looking for "#.#.#.#".

Now, when you do your build, the TFS Build Agent will be able parse the build version:

> Set workingFolder to default:  C:\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.58
>
> Executing the powershell script: C:\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.58\NuGetPackager.ps1
>
> Getting version number from build
>
> BUILD_BUILDNUMBER: Planning.Domain.Library-CI_1.0.7
>
> Version: 1.0.7

Answer (score 0):

If you look at https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/NugetPackager/NuGetPackager.ps1 :

```
if ($b_versionByBuild)
{
    Write-Verbose "Autoversion: Getting version number from build"
    ##Get Version from Build
    # Regular expression pattern to find the version in the build number 
    # and then apply it to the assemblies
    $VersionRegex = "\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
```

Support for 3 part build numbers came from this commit:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/commit/233c112bc06b91964a559090b8acfd4452cdec0b

Before this commit the regular expresion was just `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+`. So maybe you have an outdated task code in your TFS.

I just checked my on-premise TFS 2015. It cannot parse 3 number version.

Comment: I'm using TFS 2015 Update 3.